# react native render an image

Tags: react-native

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = ({ item }) => {
  const imageSource = require(`./assets/${item}.png`);

  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={imageSource} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

result:

```
error: 
components\multipleProductsImageReader.tsx: 
components\multipleProductsImageReader.tsx:Invalid call at line 4: 
require("../assets/" + item + ".png")
```

How to render the image in react-native dynamically? like my sample above.

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering your Image as shown below:

```
 <Image source={require(imageSource)} />
```

This will render your image dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

First of all print **item** result on **console log** if image have a already file extension then remove .png from require(`./assets/${item}.png`);

Note :- Must check dynamic **item** image path exist in local **assets** folder.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = ({ item }) => {
  const imageSource = require(`./assets/${item}.png`); 
  return (
    <View>
      {imageSource && <Image source={imageSource} /> } // New Line
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```